# Going to example.com redirects to example.com/www

Tags: domain, redirect, ovh

So firstly I'm not entirely sure if this is the right place to ask but I couldn't find another stack site relevant to servers so.

Recently I bought a domain with OVH, and have setup the site with an index page and such. My issue is every time I type the domain into the URL bar and press enter, it redirects me to `www.example.com/www`. I can't seem to find anything about it when I search online.

This is the server storage on the OVH site:

[image]

And here is the .htaccess:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

However, after I remove the `/www` from the URL, it doesn't redirect me to it again and goes to the normal website without any sub-folders.